# Azure IoT Hub missing in Azure IoT Edge installation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I have a Raspberry 3B+ with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server installed.
This device should work as an Azure IoT Edge device. For that purpose i have made all steps like in the Microsoft documentation, without getting any error. I used the following repository from microsoft as shown in the documentation 
But if i check the IoT Edge installation the IoT Hub container is missing, which should be part of the installation.

Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-single-device-linux-symmetric?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=azure-portal%2Cubuntu

Does anyone have the same problem?

Images from PowerShell:
[IoT Edge Check Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVQuk.jpg)
[IoT Edge installed version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axVoi.jpg)
[IoT Edge list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6arX.jpg)
[IoT Edge system status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mApCB.jpg)
[Azure portal status of IoT Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sPQa.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying Azure IoT Edge for the first time, only the edgeAgent module will spin up.

Once a (custom) module is assigned to the Edge device, using the deployment manifest, the edgeHub module will be loaded and started, together with the new module.

Please check this behavior.

Comment: Hello, as you explained i finished the tutorial with the first edge module and everything works fine. Thank you very much for your help!